# Get data for each month from defined month up to current month

Tags: php, mysql

I need to provide monthly reports of bandwidth used from our mysql database since a particular month and year e.g. November, 2009. I can output the correct data for any particular month using the following query;

```
$query='SELECT SUM(radacct.AcctInputOctets) AS uploads,SUM(radacct.AcctOutputOctets) AS downloads FROM radacct WHERE radacct.AcctStartTime BETWEEN "2010-11-00" AND "2010-12-00"';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<tr><td>December</td><td>'.$uploads.'</td><td>'.$downloads.'</td></tr>';
```

I need to put this into a loop which starts from a defined month i.e. $start='2009-11-00' and prints out a record for each month up to and including the current month. Regardless of what I try, I cant get it to work!

Comment: You say "regardless of what you try", what have you tried? It seems a fairly simple loop, adding a month to the start and end dates until a specified date, would suffice.

Comment: first you will need some month generator and calculate how many months there are to be queried (N times).. and well then it's just loop from 0 to N and generating month, sending it for query and adding results.. not very good at php so just idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a grouping parameter:

```
SELECT year(radacct.AcctStartTime), month(radacct.AcctStartTime), ...
FROM ...
WHERE radacct.AcctStartTime > '2010-09-00'
GROUP BY year(radacct.AcctStartTime), month(radacct.AcctStartTime)
```

Which would give you summary data for every year/month that has at least one entry in the database, since Sep. 2010.

Comment: What an extremely elegant solution, much faster than expected as well.